Multiple firebase projects for different environments in flutter app, iOS not working
Background
I'm trying to get a Flutter app deployed that switches what firebase project it is using depending on environment. I have two firebase projects, one for development and another for production. The production project only has two apps in it, the android and iOS apps which both have bundle ids of com.myapp.prod.
The way that we had it go about switching firebase projects was in our GitHub action workflow, which would replace the following files depending on which environment we were building and deploying for: firebase.json, firebase_options.dart, google-service.json, and GoogleService-Info.plist. I show an example of what I mean below.
- name: Move GoogleService-Info.plist file
  run: |
    mv ./firebase_config/${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT }}/GoogleService-Info.plist ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist
    cat ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist

- name: Move proper firebase.json file over
  run: |
    rm ./firebase.json
    mv ./firebase_config/${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT }}/firebase.json ./firebase.json

- name: Move proper firebase_options.dart file over
  run: |
    rm ./lib/firebase_options.dart
    mv ./firebase_config/${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT }}/firebase_options.dart ./lib/firebase_options.dart

This ultimately worked for android's deployment (the app worked fine), but not iOS (it would white screen). We noticed that the only way to fix this issue was to go ahead and delete the aforementioned files and rerun flutterfire configure and pick the project that we want and then build for that same environment and not replace the aforementioned files in our workflow. This was confusing as flutterfire configure would really just regenerate the same aforementioned files that our workflow was replacing so there was really no obvious difference. But it worked.
Obviously, this isn't ideal as we would have to run the fluttterfire configure command each time and select the proper firebase environment project before pushing out a build when ideally it should just work.
The official documentation also makes it sound like simply replacing GoogleService-Info.plist is really all that's needed but I assume that firebase.json & firebase_options.dart would also need to be replaced as those hold project-specific values.
Edit: I also wanted to add that we are using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Not sure if that would change the process at all.
What I've tried
I saw many tutorials online mentioning the Very Good Cli (example here) but I avoided those as they seemed to be working with creating a new flutter project.
Following guide
I tried following this guide starting from step 3 (as steps 1 is firebase configuration and steps 2 was talking about flavors for android but our android works just fine). Tldr on what was done is below

Created dev and prod schemes
Created Debug-dev & Debug-prod, Release-dev & Release-prod, etc configurations
Edited scheme to run with specific configurations (pictured below is what prod scheme looked like)


 
4. Created a script that copies over the proper `GoogleService-Info.plist` depending on the build configuration
There are some steps I left out above to just keep it short but every sub-step included under step 3 was included. No, I'm not using Firebase authentication so that portion didn't apply. This did not work.
Running flutterfire configure for each environment that we need
Then, I followed this stackoverflow post answer. The steps I took were as follows.

Removed firebase.json, firebase_options.dart from project
Run below command and selected dev project, this generated firebase.json, firebase_options.dart and google-services.json. This did not auto generate the GoogleService-Info.plist and so I manually went into the dev firebase project and downloaded that from the iOS app in there.

flutterfire config \ --ios-bundle-id=com.myapp.dev \ --android-package-name=com.myapp.dev


Moved files around


Repeated steps 2 + 3 above but for prod project

Added code to main.dart to choose the proper firebase_options_{env}.dart file depending on .env variable

Added script in XCode build phase that will copy over the proper GoogleService-Info.plist file depending on configuration

firebase.json & google-services.json are still being replaced within the workflow


This just resulted in my app crashing on my physical iOS device. I can supply the full crashlog.crash file if needed but here's the beginning portion
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Runner [24559]

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1984cd08c __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:249)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1957cf2e4 objc_exception_throw + 88 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1985c8648 +[NSException raise:format:] + 128 (NSException.m:0)
3   FirebaseCore                    0x1049fc298 0x1049f4000 + 33432
4   Runner                          0x1047583a8 0x104750000 + 33704
5   Runner                          0x10475850c 0x104750000 + 34060
6   UIKitCore                       0x19b0a8c00 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 320 (UIApplication.m:2577)
7   UIKitCore                       0x19b0a6118 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3016 (UIApplication.m:3013)
8   UIKitCore                       0x19af7f994 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 960 (UIApplication.m:4875)

Things to note
My development firebase project has an iOS app with the com.myapp.prod bundle id. My production firebase project has an iOS app with the same bundle id in it. Would there be issues there? (The one in dev exists because before the prod build was using the dev firebase app).
At this point, I'm kind of at a loss as to what will make this iOS flutter app to work with switching firebase projects depending on environment.

It sounds like you've tried a lot. I can assure you that it is possible to get it to work without running flutterfire config. I know this because I don't:) schemes are the way to do it.

I think this article is still valid: https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b

I think that article set the base for me when setting up different flavors for at least 4 different environments per OS (Android & iOS). All built and deployed to the stores without fastlane etc using only what is available in Azure pipelines or Github actions.
